# Docusign API - expired_client_token

Tags: api, docusignapi, postman-collection-runner

[image]

I'm using Postman collection for Docusign API,but I'm getting following error. can anybody help me to understand how do I resolve this?

Refernce link - https://developers.docusign.com/tools/postman/

[YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mV73U2tg9c0)

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization Code you are using ({{codeFromUrl}}) is only valid for 2 minutes upon generation after which it will expire and return this error. You can generate a new authorization code or use the refresh token from your previous request to generate a new access token.